# Adding Mailto in Markdown element on Sharepoint site

Tags: email

I'm trying to add a mailto link to my Sharepoint site. I know the syntax, but somehow it adds a slash to the email-address.

```
[Click here to open a template email](mailto:abc@xyz.com?Subject=Subject%20Text&Body=Thank%20you)
```

This results in the following:

[image: Example]

Any idea how I can stop the slash from being added?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is bizarre, I could replicate the same issue.

As a workaround, I've discovered, that you can add two slashes after `mailto:` it seems to solve the problem

```
[Click here to open a template email](mailto://abc@xyz.com?Subject=Subject%20Text&Body=Thank%20you)
```

Comment: Wow great find!! That indeed solves it :)

Comment: As of Oct 21, 2021, this workaround does not work: it just adds two slashes to the email address in the mail client. :-(

Comment: @DaveMulligan. That's awful. But at least on my tenant it's still works. I just checked it.